# Variable declaration problem with Symfony

Tags: symfony

I would like to create a cart for an e-commerce site, but Symfony tells me that the $dataPanier variable does not exist.

Here are the codes:

This code allows you to create a cart:

```
  `` public function add(Produit $produit, SessionInterface $session){
     // On recupère le panier actuel
     $panier = $session->get("panier", []);
     $id = $produit->getId();
     //On créer un tableau
     if(!is_array($panier)){
        $panier = [];
     }
     //si le panier n'est pas vide on l'incrémente de 1
    if(!empty ($panier[$id])){
        $panier[$id]++;
    }
    //si le panier est vide on ajoute 1
    else{
         $panier[$id] = 1;
    }
  //ON sauvegarde dans la session
  $session->set("panier", $panier);
 
  return $this->redirectToRoute("panier_index");
 
}
```

This code allows you to make a loop of the cart:

```
 `` public function index(SessionInterface $session, ProduitRepository $produitRepository):         Response
{   
    $panier = $session->get("panier", []);//On recuperer la session panier et si jamais elle est vide on recuperer un tableau vide 
    //On fabrique les données 
    $dataPanier = [];//créer une variable et on l'initialise a un tableau vide 
    $total = 0;//sers a calculer le total des prix 

    foreach($panier as $id => $quantite){//sert a bouclée sur le panier pour y recuperer l'id et la quantité
        
          $produit = $produitRepository->findBy($id);//Permet de recuperer un produit grace a la methode findAll() à partir de sont identifiant 
         
          $dataPanier[] = [  //Créer un tableau pour stocker des information sur un panier, la clé "produit" contiendrait le nom ou la référence du produit
            //et la clés "quantité" contiendrait la quantité de se produit dans le panier.
            "produit" => $produit,
            "quantite" => $quantite
           ];
          $total += $produit->getPrice() * $quantite;//permet de calculer d'un produit par la quantité commandé et en ajoutant ce montant au coût total deja accumulé.
         
    }
    return $this->render('panier/index.html.twig', compact("dataPanier", "total"));
}
```

And code allows to display on the user page that is in the loop:

```
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Produit</th>
               <th>Prix</th>
               <th>Quantité</th>
               <th>Total</th>
               <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
       
            {% for element in dataPanier %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{produit.titre}}</td>
                    <td>{{produit.prix}}</td>
                    <td>{{quantite }}</td>
                    <td>{{produit.prix * quantite}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                
            {% endfor %}
       
        </tbody>

   </table>
```

I checked if the $dataPanier variable is outside the foreach loop, I also checked if it was spelled correctly, but it always sends me the same error.

Comment: `$repo->findBy` returns an array not a single object. And you probably need to use things like `element.produit.titre`.  Might save yourself some time if you follow some of the basic examples in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to see where the error exactly is without a Profiler log, but I presume you have a mistake in this part:

```
{% for element in dataPanier %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{produit.titre}}</td>
        <td>{{produit.prix}}</td>
        <td>{{quantite }}</td>
        <td>{{produit.prix * quantite}}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>               
{% endfor %}
```

You're trying to access the `produit` element that may not exist. Try to change it to `element.produit`:

```
{% for element in dataPanier %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ element.produit.titre }}</td>
        <td>{{ element.produit.prix }}</td>
        <td>{{ element.quantite }}</td>
        <td>{{ element.produit.prix * element.quantite }}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>               
{% endfor %}
```